# Highcharts columns(min,max) colors

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a **highcharts** graph with multiple columns. I want the **two** columns(***min***,***max***) to have different colors. Is that possible?

Comment: https://api.highcharts.com/highmaps/colorAxis.maxColor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set individual color for a point for example in this way:

```
series: [{
  type: 'column',
  data: [{
    y: 1,
    color: 'purple'
  }, ...]
}]
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6m4e8x0y/4912/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.data.color

Comment: But min,max values could be in random positions and not in first,last column.Is there a way to find those two positions?

Comment: Hi @Man, You can use `load` event to find points with the highest and the lowest `y` value and update thier colors, for example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6m4e8x0y/4913/